# Anthracycline nomenclature - doxorubicin

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, molecular-structure, molecules

[image: Doxorubicin]

Why $\ce{-OCH3}$ is Number 3? I think that $\ce{-OCH3}$ Appropriates Number one.

Comment: Do you have a reference to support your thought process?

Comment: I am not good at English.
I just want to know why that replacement is number three.

Comment: The red numbers shown in the picture are not related to nomenclature. Clearly, the locant for the methoxy group is '1', and there is no locant '13'.

Answer (score 1):

According to both [PubChem](https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/Doxorubicin) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxorubicin), the IUPAC name of Doxorubicin is (7*S*,9*S*)-7-[(2*R*,4*S*,5*S*,6*S*)-4-Amino-5-hydroxy-6-methyloxan-2-yl]oxy-6,9,11-trihydroxy-9-(2-hydroxyacetyl)-4-methoxy-8,10-dihydro-7*H*-tetracene-5,12-dione, which probably is the correct naming. To answer your question about why $\ce{-OCH3}$ is number 4 (actually it is number 4, not 3 as you indicated), I put both numbering and and corresponding names in following image:

[image: IUPAC name of Doxorubicin]

I think you have enough knowledge to understand why numbering in $\bf{A}$ is preferred. For instance, the principle functional group is 5,12-dione, which does not change in both numbering. Yet, for the numbering of two major substitutions in tetracene nucleus are changed: it is (7,9)- versus (8,10)-. Further, complete locant set is (4,5,6,7,9,9,11,12) versus (1,5,6,8,8,10,11,12). In addition, it is (7*H*) versus (10*H*). I hope you got the point.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but if you are OK with some critics, then there are some things I would point out: **1**. [Neither Wikipedia nor PubChem can be considered trustworthy sources for the nomenclature](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3121/41328). **2**. Ideally, one should be able to present information without relying on colors or substantial amounts of text on the illustrations (such post appears less professional and are a barrier for color blind and overall visually impaired users). **3**. The question is borderline HW and is also based on a false premise.

Comment: @ andselisk♦: I do believe you and your points are well taken. I have habit using color to emphasize my points (you'd realize if you look at my publications). I'd keep those in my mind in future perspectives. Only I can't stand is pointless downvoting, that's all my complain about. Thanks for the concern.

Comment: Downvoted because the explanation why **A** is preferred over **B** is not correct. It is not about (7,9)- versus (8,10)-. The parent structure of **A** has eight substituent prefixes (4,6,7,8,9,9,10,11) that are all considered together, not just (7,9) since there are no “major substitutions” in nomenclature. **A** is actually preferred simply because the locant 7 for the indicated hydrogen is lower than 10. (…)

Comment: (…) Anyway, the name of the parent structure actually is 7,8,9,10-tetrahydrotetracene-5,12-dione and not 8,10-dihydro-7H-tetracene-5,12-dione, which makes the comparison of the indicated hydrogen in **A** and **B** irrelevant from the start.